# RxSwift ConnectableObservable missing autoconnect

Tags: swift, rx-java, rx-swift

**Question**

I'm porting a project that uses RxJava to RxSwift. There is a ConnectableObservable that uses autoconnect(). How would I port this to RxSwift? I'm looking for a similar feature or work around.

**Information**

I was looking to use refcount() in RxSwift but once the subscriber number goes to 0 it'll stop where autoconnect() would continue. According to these [release notes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases), autoConnect works like only the first half of refCount, or more precisely, it is similar in behavior to refCount(), except that it doesn't disconnect when subscribers are lost.

Comment: http://www.tailec.com/blog/understanding-publish-connect-refcount-share

Comment: @iWheelBuy ty. Based on the link it looks like I'll be forced to call connect manually if I want things to run when no subscribers. Here's a link to what RxJava can do with a replay(). I just use autoconnect() to return an observable and not have the extra boiler plate of calling connect on every subscriber.      

https://github.com/HIFILEO/ReactiveArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/reactivearchitecture/nowplaying/viewmodel/NowPlayingViewModel.java#L211

Comment: It you want your observable to work when no subscribers, you can bind your observable to some Variable. And when new subscriber wants to connect, it just connects to a `variable.asObservable` and will immediately get the latest result and all future results.

Comment: I'm no Swift developer but the [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableAutoConnect.java) of `autoConnect` is quite straightforward: have an atomic counter and on each `subscribe` call, increment it. When it reaches the desired minimum subscriber count, issue the `connect` to the `ConnectableObservable`.

Comment: @akamokd a good recommendation but RxSwfit does not allow extension of an Observable so it's tricky to create custom observable extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I took @akamokd's advice, I just created my own. Since I only needed autoConnect() it's was pretty simple.

```
extension ConnectableObservableType {
    func autoconnect() -> Observable<E> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            return self.do(onSubscribe: {
                _ = self.connect()
            }).subscribe { (event: Event<Self.E>) in
                switch event {
                case .next(let value):                   
                    observer.on(.next(value))
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.on(.error(error))
                case .completed:
                    observer.on(.completed)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the line `_ = self.connect()` returns a `Disposable` which is unhandled. Might this cause memory leaks?

Comment: I'm no Rx expert, but so maybe this isn't needed, but this seems like prudent handling of disposables:

`return Observable.create { observer in
    var disposables = [Disposable]()
    let outer = self.do(onSubscribe: {
        disposables.append(self.connect())
    }).subscribe { 
// "forward" events to 'observer'
}
    
    disposables.append(outer)
    return Disposables.create(disposables)
}`